# Prove the following $\frac{\Omega(f(n))}{\Omega(g(n))} \subseteq \Omega(\frac{f(n)}{g(n)})$

Tags: asymptotics

I want to prove the following:
$$\frac{\Omega(f(n))}{\Omega(g(n))} \subseteq \Omega(\frac{f(n)}{g(n)})$$
I wonder if its true?
What about using $n$ and $n^2$?

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: The statement is false.  It sounds like you have a counterexample in mind; what do you mean "what about using $n$ and $n^2$"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement is false.

$$f(n)=n^4,g(n)=n^2\\ n^4\in \Omega(f(n)),n^3\in \Omega(g(n))\\\frac{n^4}{n^3} \subseteq \Omega(\frac{n^4}{n^2})\\\\n \nsubseteq \Omega(n^2)$$